# How to assign a value to an array of structures in C?

Tags: c, arrays, file, struct

There is a function load that reads an array of structures from a binary file and returns this array.It works correctly.But the problem is that I can not assign an array of structures the value that the load function returns.

```
struct tickets
{
    char plane [7];
    char zona [13];
    int rate;
    int cost;

};

struct tickets* load(char * filename)
{
    FILE * file;
    char *symbol;
    int m = sizeof(int);
    int n, i;
    int *pti = (int *)malloc(m);

    if ((file = fopen(filename, "r")) == NULL)
    {
        perror("Error occured while opening file");

    }
    symbol = (char *)pti;
    while (m>0)
    {
        i = getc(file);
        if (i == EOF) break;
        *symbol = i;
        symbol++;
        m--;
    }
    n = *pti;
    struct tickets* ptr = (struct tickets *) malloc(n * sizeof(struct tickets));
    symbol = (char *)ptr;
    while ((i= getc(file))!=EOF)
    {
        *symbol = i;
        symbol++;
    }

    fclose(file);
    return  ptr;
}
int main(void)
{
    char * filename = "p.dat";
    struct tickets* ticket = NULL;
    ticket = load(filename);
}
```

Comment: Please show the calling code, that's probably where the problem is. And what is the problem? Is there an error message when you compile it? When you run it? Or does it just not do what you expect?

Comment: BTW your `pti` pointer is odd. It points to a single `int`, there is no need to do dynamic allocation for this. This looks overly complicated. Please explain what the first while loop is supposed to do....

Comment: regarding: `int *pti = (int *)malloc(m);`  1) in C, the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  casting just clutters the code and is error prone.  Suggest removing the cast.  2) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful, call `perror( "your error message" );`  This will properly output both your error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred to `stderr`.  usually, after such an error, the next statement will be: `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );` because most errors cannot be recovered from

Comment: in function: `main()` this statement: `ticket = load(filename);` is setting the variable `ticket`, but that variable is never used.

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  first because it is missing the `#include` statements for the needed header files.  Are you expecting us to guess which header files you actually included?

Comment: the posted code will have radically different results, depending on if the underlying hardware is Big Endian or Little Endian.  This needs to be corrected

Comment: OT; the posted code contains some 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis.  I.E. 7, 13.  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest using `#define` statements or a `enum` statement to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then use those meaningful names throughout the code

Comment: regarding:  `int *pti = malloc(m);`  The function: `malloc()` is expecting a `size_t` parameter, not a `int` parameter

Comment: the posted code contains two memory leaks.  Where a memory allocation is made using `malloc()` but those memory allocations are never returned via calls to `free()`

Comment: suggest learning about the function: `read()` as that will greatly speed up the execution of the reading of the file and greatly shrink (and simplify) your code

Comment: Per your code, in function: `main()` the variable: `ticket` is a pointer to the array of `struct tickets` that were read from the input file.  However, `main()` has no idea as to how many of those struct instances are in that array

Comment: the first integer, being read from the file, has to be a fixed length (say 4 bytes)  but different compilers/CPUs, etc can have different length integers.  Suggest fixing the length in the file to 4 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

the following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. performs the desired functionality
3. properly checks for errors
4. informs the `main()` function as to how many instances of `struct tickets` were read
5. informs the user when any error occurs
6. cleans up after itself
7. eliminates one of the calls to `malloc()`
8. uses the function: `fread()` to avoid problems with `little/big Endian`
9. documents why each header file is included
10. assumes the ticket count (first 4 bytes of file) is in binary
11. incorporates appropriate horizontal and vertical spacing for readability

caveat: since no example input file posted, this code is not tested

and now, the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>    // perror(), NULL, FILE*, EOF, 
                      // fopen(), fclose(), fread()
#include <stdlib.h>   // malloc(), free(), exit(), EXIT_FAILURE

#define MAX_PLANE_LEN 7
#define MAX_ZONA_LEN  13
#define COUNT_LEN 4

struct tickets
{
    char plane [ MAX_PLANE_LEN ];
    char zona [ MAX_ZONA_LEN ];
    int rate;
    int cost;
};


struct tickets* load( char * filename, size_t * ticketCount )
{
    FILE * fp;
    if ( ! (fp = fopen( filename, "r" )) )
    {
        perror( "Error occured while opening file" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    size_t bytesRead = fread( ticketCount, 1, COUNT_LEN, fp );      
    if( bytesRead != COUNT_LEN )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "failed to read count of number of instances of 'struct tickets'\n" );
        fclose( fp );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    struct tickets* ptr =  malloc( *ticketCount * sizeof( struct tickets ) );
    if( ! ptr )
    {
        perror( "malloc failed" );
        fclose( fp );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    for( size_t i = 0; i < *ticketCount; i++ )
    {
        size_t numBytes = fread( &(ptr[i]), 1, sizeof( struct tickets ), fp );
        if( numBytes != sizeof( struct tickets ) )
        {
            perror( "read of a struct ticket failed" );
            fclose( fp );
            free( ptr );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }
    }

    fclose( fp );
    return  ptr;
}


int main( void )
{
    char * filename = "p.dat";
    size_t ticketCount = 0;
    struct tickets* ticket = load( filename, &ticketCount );
    // ...
    free( ticket );
}
```

Comment: the reading of the number of instances of the `struct tickets` may need to be changed to use `if( fscanf( fp, "%zu", *ticketCount, ) != 1) { //handle error }` rather than `fread()` and its' error checking